# Save binary image to file

Tags: node.js

I make an API request which [returns a binary image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#response-for-getting-the-photo). How can I save it to a file like `photo.png` on my machine? Doing some research, I've tried the following but when I open the image, my machine says it's damaged:

```
const buffer = new Buffer(imageBinary);
const b64 = buffer.toString("base64");
const path = `temp/${userId}`;
const url = path + "/photo.png";
if (!fs.existsSync(path)) fs.mkdirSync(path);
if (fs.existsSync(url)) fs.unlinkSync(url)
fs.createWriteStream(url).write(b64);
return url;
```

Edit: Here is the binary data FYI: https://gist.github.com/AskYous/1fd26dc0eb02b4ec1672dcf5c61a34df

Comment: A base64 encoded byte buffer isn't going to be interpreted by a PNG decoder.  What is the format of `imageBinary`?  Why are you encoding it with base64?

Comment: @zero298 I was just following another website. I think the format is .jpeg which I tested as well. I edited my post to include the binary.

Comment: Can you post the url you download the image from please?

Comment: It required authentication. You can see a sample [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/graph-explorer/?request=me/photo/$value&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com). Just press **Run Query** on the right.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to re-encode the buffer as base64. Just write the binary buffer as is:

```
fs.createWriteStream(url).write(imageBinary);
```

Comment: @AskYous Try invoking `file` command on the file and see what it reports.

Comment: It just outputted: `photo.jpeg: data`.

Comment: I added the binary string in my post.